# CCXT - Create a market order by only specifying quote currency amount

Tags: ccxt

From what I have seen CCXT does not provide functionality for creating an order of type:

*"I want to spend 10 USDT to buy BTC"*

Instead, the only thing you can do is to specify the amount of the base currency(BTC) you want to buy, like in the examples below:

```
const order = await exchange.createOrder(symbol, 'market', 'buy', amount, price);
```

OR

```
const symbol = 'BTC/USD';
const amount = 2;
const price = 9000;
cost = amount * price;
const order = await exchange.createMarketBuyOrder (symbol, cost);
```

Is there something that I have missed that could provide the functionality I need ?

The only solution I could think of is to get the base currency's price and calculate the percentage of it that equals to 10 USDT so I can then use that as the `amount` in the examples above.

Answer (score 5):

Most exchange apis only take the base quantity, so you would need to do a conversion based on the price of the market

```
const ccxt = require("ccxt");

const exchange = new ccxt.binance({
  apiKey: '...',
  secret: '...',
  options: {},
});

const get_amount_from_quote = async (quote_amount, symbol) => {
  const tickers = await exchange.fetch_tickers();
  const price = tickers[symbol]["close"];
  return quote_amount / price;
};

const symbol = "ETH/USDT";
const amount = await get_amount_from_quote(10, symbol);
const order = await exchange.createOrder(
  symbol,
  "market",
  "buy",
  amount,
  price
);
```

---

Some exchanges, like Binance, specify that you can pass in `quoteOrderQuantity` in [their api](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#test-new-order-trade)

[image: Binance Api quote order quantity documentation]

And you can always pass in exchange specific parameters through the `params` argument

```
const order = await exchange.createOrder(
  symbol,
  "market",
  "buy",
  undefined,
  price,
  {
    quoteOrderQty: 10,
  }
);
```

Comment: Note that quoteOrderQuantity is only for spot.

Answer (score 0):

you able to do it with placing market order **(only some exchanges)**

```
def buy_coins(exchange, symbol, amount_usdt_to_spend):
    exchange.options['createMarketBuyOrderRequiresPrice'] = False
    order = exchange.create_market_order(symbol, 'buy', amount_usdt_to_spend)
    return order


def sell_coins(exchange, symbol, amount_btc_to_sell):
    exchange.options['createMarketBuyOrderRequiresPrice'] = False
    order = exchange.create_market_order(symbol, 'sell', amount_btc_to_sell)
    return order
```